# Position label above vertex feynmp 4 fermion interaction

Tags: feynmf, feynmp-auto, feynmp

I am trying to produce a Feynman diagram that is simply 2 incoming fermions meet at  a vertex v1, with 2 outgoing fermions. I wish to put a label on the vertex, above the vertex. However feynmp by default puts it to the right of the vertex and I cannot manage to fix it so it is above.

```
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(80,50)

        \fmfleft{i1,i2} \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v1,o2}
        \fmflabel{$v_1$}{v1}
        \fmfdot{v1}

    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

I have tried to put label.side=above in \fmflabel but this does not seem to take this argument. I have tried defining the vertex v1 itself like \fmf{vertex,label=g,label.side=above}{v1} but this does not work. I have also tried doing the same thing for the first fermion but this puts two labels above each leg of the fermion rather than one in the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) of feynMF states (page 23):

> `\fmflabel` gives the user no control on the placement of the the label
>   (use the `\fmfv` macro for a more fine-grained control)

The `\fmfv` macro, among other things, has arguments `label` for the text of a label and `label.angle` for the placement of the label.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(80,50)

        \fmfleft{i1,i2} \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v1,o2}
        \fmfv{label=$v_1$,label.angle=90}{v1}
        \fmfdot{v1}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you.